# Tensor algebra mod by an ideal

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, tensor-products, quotient-spaces

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space and $I$ be an ideal. The tensor algebra of $V$ is defined by $$T(V)= \bigoplus_n V^{\otimes n}$$

Is it true that $T(V)/I $ is isomorphic to $$\bigoplus_n \left(V^{\otimes n}/I
\right)?$$

It seems like the ideal doesn't matter if we put the direct sum outside the quotient.

Comment: Do you mean $V^{\otimes n}/(I\cap V^{\otimes n})$?

Comment: No. What I mean is that if I take the direct sum of the quotient (V^{\otimes n}/I), is it isomorphic to T(V)/I?

Comment: How do you mean that quotient?

Comment: Just the usual quotient algebra, if I get your question right.

Comment: First, $V^{\otimes n}$ in itself is not an algebra. Second, we don't have $I\subseteq V^{\otimes n}$.

Comment: I see. Thank you!!